# IndexOutOfBoundsException on a print statement

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a print statement that is triggering an exception `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Here's the code:
**MAIN METHOD**

```
public class AdvDotComLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdvDotComTable table = new AdvDotComTable();
        table.createTable(5,5);
    }
}
```

**TABLE CLASS**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdvDotComTable {
    public boolean createTable(int rows, int columns) {
        if (rows == 26) {
            //When true is returned, the program will let the user know they have to choose a lower number
            return true;
        }
        String[] dotComs = {"Pets.com", "Amazon.com", "Target.com", "Apple.com", "Microsoft.com", "Steampowered.com"};
        ArrayList<Character> row = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<Integer> column = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        char[] letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
        int number = 0;
        int rows2 = rows;
        int columns2 = columns;
        while (rows2 != 0 && columns2 != 0) {
            row.add(letters[number]);
            if(number == columns) {
                column.add(number);
                number = 0;
                columns2--;
            }
            System.out.println(row.get(number) + "" + column.get(number));
            number++;
            rows2--;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
    at AdvDotComTable.createTable(AdvDotComTable.java:23)
    at AdvDotComLauncher.main(AdvDotComLauncher.java:4)
```

I have no idea what is causing this problem, and any assistance would be appreciated. I am an amateur developer just trying to learn, so it's probably a silly mistake (sorry about that). 
Thanks in advance,
Lyfe

Comment: It isn't 'on a print statement'. `println()` does not appear in your stack trace. It is at `ArrayList.get()`, and it is because the index *is* out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that your code

```
System.out.println(row.get(number) + "" + column.get(number));
```

will fail.

As before this code, you are adding value into row list, at index number but your column list is still empty with no element. If the list does not have an element, you are expected to have exception. Just like below code

```
List test = new ArrayList();
System.out.println(test.get(0));
```

Comment: Hi, I added '0' to the list with column.add(0);. However, I'm still getting an indexoutofbounds exception.

Comment: The idea is same. If you added only one element to list and are calling index  > 0 then you will get exception. When you are calling get, make sure the index you pass is less than the size of list. In your question, value of number keeps on increasing...

Answer (score 0):

The API for [ArrayList's get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) method is clear enough on this.

> Throws:
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

In your case, the index >=size() is what is happening.

Comment: Hi, I added '0' to the list with column.add(0);. However, I'm still getting an indexoutofbounds exception.

Comment: @Lyfe. Are you adding it everytime you go inside the while loop? The problem is that you are trying to print column.get() everytime, but it is not being populated always. And everytime you are increasing "number". Last time you were getting OutOfBound for index=0, after hardcoding your column.add(0), you would now be getting it at index=1 which means you passed the first iteration of the loop, but failed in the 2nd one

Answer (score 0):

To better understand when your code fails, you can debug your code at some points. This is very helpful for the new developers to learn and understand what's going on.

You can also look at the explanation and go to the lone where the cods fails. The beginning of the error occus at line 23.

```
System.out.println(row.get(number) + "" + column.get(number));
```

and you get the `IndexOutOfBoundException`. This is saying you that at some point you are trying to get beyond the size limits of your array. So, what you can do to gain some time is pit a debug point here and also add a case to enter debugging where the row or column is bigger or equal to 26 and continue debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The **IndexOutOfBoundException** throws at the following line e.i -

```
 System.out.println(row.get(number) + "" + column.get(number));
```

The exception thrown because there is no any insertion happen in the ArrayList **column** and it always be empty that's why `column.get(number)` throws  **IndexOutOfBoundException** exception.

If you make the changes in the SOP as following then you get the output something like  -

```
System.out.println(row + " " + column);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[A] []
[A, B] []
[A, B, C] []
[A, B, C, D] []
[A, B, C, D, E] []
```

I think the issue is in the if condition which is false in very first pass and then throws the exception check the if condition

```
   if(number == columns) {
        column.add(number);
        number = 0;
        columns2--;
    }
```